# Java Selenium xpath, how can I click this attribute?

Tags: java, css, selenium-webdriver

I have an html snippet from a [site](https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/jackets/kiu5tqj83/wpwr1zkit)

```
<a class="" data-images="{&quot;detail_url&quot;:&quot;//assets.supremenewyork.com/156246/ma/VKFiZkcDgXY.jpg&quot;,&quot;zoomed_url&quot;:&quot;//assets.supremenewyork.com/156246/zo/VKFiZkcDgXY.jpg&quot;}" data-style-name="White" data-style-id="21049" data-sold-out="false" data-description="null" href="/shop/jackets/kiu5tqj83/myh25duje?alt=0" data-no-tubolink="data-no-tubolink">
    <img width="32" height="32" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/156246/sw/VKFiZkcDgXY.jpg" alt="Vkfizkcdgxy">
</a>
```

I was wondering how I could access the attribute's value with selenium & java, then click it. The attribute in question is: `data-style-name="White"`. I've tried doing:

```
WebElement white = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//class[@data-style-name='White']"));
white.click();
```

but I keep getting errors saying:

> "Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id=details]/ul/li[3]/a[2]"}
>   Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds"

Comment: Your error message doesn't match with the code you have posted. Please edit your question and update the code and/or error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XPath is incorrect. It should be

```
//a[@data-style-name='White']
```

or one of these CSS selectors

```
a[data-style-name='White']
a[alt='Vkfizkcdgxy']
```

Comment: I have the same error as before when I change to your line: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@data-style-name='White']"}
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds

Comment: Can you please share error what you are getting now?

Comment: Updated my answers please check

Comment: It just worked, I forgot to un-comment my delay. Thank you very much!